# MySQL Ordering question - yet another question!

Tags: mysql, group-by

Ok, have the following code:

```
SELECT q21 as Comment, q21coding  AS Description 
FROM `tresults_acme` 
WHERE q21 IS NOT NULL AND q21 <> '' 
ORDER BY q21coding = 'Other', q21coding = 'Positive comments', Count ASC
```

This brings back the following (excerpt):

```
Text                                                     Description
Lack of up to date equal pay cases&legislation - t...   Content needs updating
The intranet could contain more "up to date traini...   Content needs updating
Poorly set out. It is hard to find things.             Difficulty in navigating/finding content
Only use the intranet as a necessity. Will ask my ...   Difficulty in navigating/finding content
Never really use it too difficult to be honest, s ...   Difficulty in navigating/finding content
```

What I need to do is bring back the Text in a specific order basically this is where a COUNT for Description is in Ascending order - make sense?

So in the example above, the text for 'Difficulty in navigating/ finding conent' would come first as it has a count of 3, then 'Content needs updating' as it has a count of 2.

Any advice welcome!

Thanks as always,

Homer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this would work (cannot test this right now):

```
SELECT q21 as Comment, q21coding  AS Description, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tresults_acme` as t_a WHERE t_a.q21coding = Description) AS Count 
FROM `tresults_acme` 
WHERE q21 IS NOT NULL AND q21 <> '' 
ORDER BY q21coding = 'Other', q21coding = 'Positive comments', Count ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

My dear u dont have to give the value of the attributes in the order by clause, this is the mistake u have made in the code.
I am not sure but i think so after select q21 as Comment type of syntax also needs reconsideration.